# Find the value of integral $ \int_{ \mid z \mid =1} \frac{ 30z^{2}-23z+5 }{ (2z-1)^{2}(3z-1) } $

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Integral to get the result?

$$ \int_{ \mid z \mid =1}  \frac{ 30z^{2}-23z+5 }{ (2z-1)^{2}(3z-1) }  $$

with Solutions ,tnx.

Comment: What have you tried? The integrand can be partial fraction decompose, for example. (The answer is 0)

Comment: Partial fractions is indeed a great idea. But the answer isn't 0. (The rational function has a simple pole at $\infty$, so it's impossible to get 0.)

Answer (score 3):

With partial fraction decomposition you have :

$$f(z)=\frac{ 30z^{2}-23z+5 }{ (2z-1)^{2}(3z-1) } = 2\frac{1}{z-\frac{1}{3}}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{z-\frac{1}{2}}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{(z-\frac{1}{2})^2}$$

We will try to use Residue theorem now :

$Res(f,\frac{1}{3})=Res(2\frac{1}{z-\frac{1}{3}})=2$
you should also find $Res(f,\frac{1}{2})=\frac{1}{2}$ (you have to justify a bit this calculation).

So finally : $$\int_{ \mid z \mid =1}  \frac{ 30z^{2}-23z+5 }{ (2z-1)^{2}(3z-1) } dz=2\pi i(2+\frac{1}{2})=\pi i5$$

Comment: Do you know why the integral below has a different result?
$$\int_0^{2 \pi } \left(\frac{2}{\left(2 e^{i \theta }-1\right)^2}+\frac{6}{3 e^{i \theta }-1}+\frac{1}{2 e^{i \theta }-1}\right) i e^{i \theta } \, \mathrm{d}\theta=5 \pi i$$

Comment: You forgot to multiply the result by $2\pi i$.

Comment: @Shobhit oopsie i will correct

Comment: @GuilhermeThompson It seems that it is not the partial fraction decomposition of the function considered in the question.

Comment: @Jennifer, could you check it? Because I'm rather sure one can write 
$$\frac{30 z^2-23 z+5}{(2 z-1)^2 (3 z-1)}=\frac{2}{(2 z-1)^2}+\frac{6}{3 z-1}+\frac{1}{2 z-1}$$

Comment: @GuilhermeThompson oh you are right I did a mistake I thought it was $20z^2$ instead of $30z^2$ in numerator.

Comment: corrected ${}{}{}{}{}$